# (XAML) Supporting Down Key navigation in ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

- Windows Store App
- XAML

I have a ListView in a PopUp. I want to trap the Down key in a TextBox (not in PopUp) and Set Focus to the ListView. Focus works but when I press the Down key the First item in the list is Selected. I want to allow the user to navigate down through a ListView using the down key.

I must be missing something very obvious as this shouldn't be that hard.

Thanks

Comment: Which down arrow? Can you include an image?

Comment: The Down Key on the keyboard, sorry I will update the question to make it clearer

Comment: You can manually handle `KeyDown`, find the next item in the list (via `ContainerFromIndex`), then focus it using `Control.Focus`. You may need some casting though. Make sure to set `e.Handled=true`.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you're doing? Standard behavior for a ListView is for up and down keys to navigate between items and space to select. I just verified this with a stub ListView on both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Comment: @RobCaplan I am going to delete this question as I was being an idiot. I wanted the down key to move through the items yet I did NOT necessarily want the Item to be selected. I had code elsewhere that was listening to SectionChnaged and closing the PopUp. Unless you think something could be learnt by others. I don't think so

Comment: I should note that the reason I am using the TextBOx with a ListView is that I am trying to implement a Search Suggestions box since we ran into these issues with the official one. See this MSDN post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9d262b1c-a9f3-42b2-b9e0-4066abcc89be/adding-suggestions-to-searchbox-causes-app-to-crash?forum=winappswithcsharp